# Получить с шрифта какую либо букву или цифру, и получить её пиксели C#

Tags: c#, шрифты

Всем привет, мне нужно получить из шрифта букву или цифру, и перевести её в набор пикселей.
Что то типа Bitmap.GetPixel(int x, int y) но только над шрифтом. Просто есть поле Pixel[,] и я хочу на это поле вывести текст как это сделать?!
И да у меня свой класс Pixel в котором есть char, Color, int x, int y

Я сделал в итоге как говорил пользователь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot
Спасибо вам, я не знаю как отметить ваш ответ как решение так что пишу вот так[image: То чего я добивался]

Comment: Самое медленное, что можно сделать с битмапом, это `GetPixel` и `SetPixel`. Решение звучит легко: берете битмап, берете нужный `Font` нужного размера, берете `Graphics` из этого битмапа, рисуете на нем символ. Растр готов. Как получить цвет пикселя из битмапа - вы уже знаете. Вот только смысл задачи я не уловил.

Comment: @aepot - может, оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ? Там человеку то помогло... Уважаемый автор вопроса, обратите внимание, что приведенная Вами надпись демонстрирует: в шрифте есть не только черные и белые точки, на границе есть "серая" область, котрая делает надпись не такой резкой.

Comment: @S.H. чтобы написать вменяемый ответ, полезный не только для автора вопроса, надо пример кода написать, а мне сейчас некогда, да и желаения особого нет. Если желаете, можете написать ответ за меня.